# Why this Alert Dialog is not Showing on backPressed?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

> Here is my onBackPressed() :

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainScreen.this);
        String checkInVal = preferences.getString("checkIn", "");
        if (!PRE_USER_ACTIVE.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();

        } else if (MainScreen.this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("VOLUNTEERDETAILS") != null && checkInVal.equals("yes")) {
            popFragment();
        } else {
            if (Functions.iNumberOfLoadedFragments == 0) {
                String exitLog = "Exit Application", ok = "OK", cancel = "CANCEL";
                String sureLog = "Are you sure you want to exit  " + MainScreen.this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
                if (EasyPreference.with(MainScreen.this, PRE_KEY)
                        .getString(PRE_USER_LANGUAGE, PRE_LANGUAGE_ENGLISH).equalsIgnoreCase(PRE_LANGUAGE_ASSEMESS)) {

                    exitLog = "প্ৰস্থান কৰক অ্যাপ্লিকেশন";
                    sureLog = "আপুনি Our SchoolZoneৰ পৰা প্ৰস্থান কৰিবলৈ নিশ্চিতনে";
                    ok = "স্বীকাৰ কৰক";
                    cancel = "বাতিল কৰক";
                } else if (EasyPreference.with(MainScreen.this, PRE_KEY)
                        .getString(PRE_USER_LANGUAGE, PRE_LANGUAGE_ENGLISH).equalsIgnoreCase(PRE_LANGUAGE_THI)) {

                    exitLog = "ออกจากแอพพลิเคชัน";
                    sureLog = "คุณแน่ใจหรือว่าต้องการออกจาก Our SchoolZone";
                    ok = "ตกลง";
                    cancel = "ยกเลิก";
                }
                new LovelyStandardDialog(MainScreen.this)
                        .setTopColor(Functions.getBackColor())
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_white_36dp)
                        .setTitle(exitLog)
                        .setMessage(sureLog)
                        .setPositiveButton(ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                MainScreen.super.onBackPressed();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(cancel, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                            }
                        })
                        .show();

            } else if (Functions.iNumberOfLoadedFragments > 0) {
                Functions.iNumberOfLoadedFragments--;
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
}
```

> The ALertDialog needs to be shown in back button pressed from this Activity
> Instead the App just Quits to Launcher.
>
> What can be possible Issues,please reply with your valuable suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using log in each case to check which one of it is executed?

Comment: Exactly the same thing I am doing now  :<

Comment: found it Bro,  if (!PRE_USER_ACTIVE.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            Log.e("PRE_USER ACTIVE", "BACK PRESSED");
            super.onBackPressed();
          //  finish();

        }

Comment: this is executing on backpressed() @sanjeev

Comment: Have you called that onBackpressed() function in your mainactivity - oncreate() ?

Comment: Value of PRE_USER_ACTIVE is either hardcoded or you have not changed it anywhere. Assign a different value other than 1..

Comment: yes @PrajwalW i have done it

Comment: ok,i will definitely do it @sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:  **AlertDialog for exit from app**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to EXIT ?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                    finish();

                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}
```

upvote if found useful so that others can get the answer